# Inserting an input that searches Wikipedia on my website

Tags: html, search-engine, wikipedia

I would like to have an input field on my website that on submit searches Wikipedia for the input value.
I've tried to find answers here on StackOverflow and through out Google searches, but the only thing I've found is how to add Wikipedia as a search engine for various browsers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question and show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a form which uses the GET method to submit the query to Wikipedia. This will append the parameter "search" with the user's input to the URL which is the format Wikipedia is looking for.

```
<form method="get" action="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php">
  <input type="text" name="search">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [wikipedia API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) and feed it what is entered into the input and then display what comes back.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google and create a search string.
For instance, let's say your user submits the term "horses".
You can seach wikipedia using the syntax:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=horses+site=wikipedia.org
```

and then you could show the results in a new window.

This could all be done in HTML/Javascript with no back end code.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4zj8tyq/3/)